# Error con query();

Tags: pdo, sql

Buenos días,
Llevo un rato con este error y soy incapaz de solucionarlo a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano se lo agradecería muchísimo!

```
$base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$base=exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
```

La linea problemática es esta (18):

```
$registros=$base->query('SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios') >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

y este es el error que me da:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on string in
>   C:\wamp64\www\php\CRUD\index.php on line 18

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Basicamente lo que te ocurre es que estas asignando a $base el resultado del exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8") y este devuelve un string no el objeto PDO

Comment: Cierto! Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Xavi añadiría, que una buena costumbre en php cuando no sabes bien lo que te está devolviendo algo es hacerle un var_dump($variable);

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @Lithorell como sugerencia, deberías de poner tu solución como respuesta para que quede mejor organizado y la pregunta tenga una respuesta, y más cuando a Xavi le solución el problema. Saludos.

Comment: Hecho @Adriana Hernández ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas asignando a $base el resultado del exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8") y este devuelve un string no el objeto PDO.

La solucion es cambiar el = por la fecha de acceso a metodo ->

```
$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
```

Con ello tu codigo quedaría asi:

```
$base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
$registros=$base->query('SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios') >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```